# What is the best practice where to store Selenium WebDriver: on environment, in the project?

Tags: selenium

So, there are two options:

1. in the test project
2. in the PATH of the environment (on machine)

What is the best choice? What are pros and cons of these two approaches? What do you prefer personally and why?

Answer (score 1):

To put all the confusion regarding *WebDriver* location to *Rest In Peace (RIP)* with respect to:

- *Test Project* location
- `PATH` *Environmental Variable* within system [os](/questions/tagged/os)

Use the *Key* `executable_path` to override the default location and use the version specific *WebDriver* binary through it's *absolute path* as follows:

- Python with *GeckoDriver* / *Firefox*:

  - Linux/MAC OSX example:

    ```
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/path/to/geckodriver')
    ```
  - Windows example:

    ```
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe')
    ```
- Java with *ChromeDriver* / *Chrome*:

  - Linux/MAC OSX example:

    ```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
    ```
  - Windows example:

    ```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
    ```

---

### Advantage

You can use/test multiple versions of the *WebDriver* variant as follows:

- To use *ChromeDriver v79.0*:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\v79\chromedriver.exe')
  ```
- To use *ChromeDriver v78.0*:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\v78\chromedriver.exe')
  ```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: this is not related to question.